# Thread safe collection that supports removing items

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrent-programming

I cannot seem to find a .NET thread safe / concurrent collect that supports a simple Remove() function where I can either remove a specific item or pass in a predicate to remove items based on that. I have tried:

```
BlockingCollection<T>
ConcurrentQueue<T>
ConcurrentStack<T>
ConcurrentBag<T>
```

Does anyone know of a collection that supports this behavior, or do I have to create my own?

I want to be able to grab the next item from a thread-safe queue **without** removing it, and later on if a certain condition is met, proceed with removing it.

Comment: "grab the next item ... and later ... proceed with removing it" - and what can the other threads do in the mean time?

Comment: There are only 2 threads, one adds items to the queue, the other takes items off and fires an event. If the event returns successful, then that item must be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)? It has a [`TryRemove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129.aspx) method, so if you think of the key as a predicate, then you will be removing the correct item.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I need. However it'd still be nice to have a simple list as I have no need for key/val pairs.

Comment: @Sean I don't know of anything like that in C# (or at least nothing out of the box). You can just ignore the value and use the `ConcurrentDictionary` like a `List` (with no duplicate values). You can iterate over the keys just like you can iterate over a list and about the only overhead of the value is that it uses slightly more memory. You can minimize that by using a very small primitive (`bool` or something).

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure `ConcurrentQueue<T>` doesn't suit your needs? It has a `TryPeek` method and a `TryDequeue` method that do exactly what you describe in the last paragraph.

Comment: I need it to support a Remove() function where I can either remove a specific item or pass in a predicate to remove items based on that. TryDequeue() for instance just removes the next item in the queue, not necessarily the specific one you want.

Comment: OK, but in a queue you can only take an item from the head, so what you want is not a queue... and in that case, what do you mean by the "next" item?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here do not directly answer the question, or provide limitations which may be undesirable. For example, ConcurrentDictionary uses keys preventing duplicate instances from being added.

SynchronizedCollection seems to be what is needed as it is thread-safe and contains a Remove method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Code example:

```
SynchronizedCollection<string> FilePathsToIgnore = new SynchronizedCollection<string>();
...

FilePathsToIgnore.Add(someFileName);
...

if(FilePathsToIgnore.Contains(fileName))
{
    FilePathsToIgnore.Remove(fileName);
}
```